# Handle tableview did select row at index path delegate method in container view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, containment

I have two view controllers added as a child view controllers in containerview controller and one view controller has AQGridView with song albums as items.When i select the album how can i navigate to another view controller that displays songs details.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UINavigation for such kind of scenario .
 Because when you want to navigate b/w multiple view controllers, then UINavigation controller is the best option.

So in your app delegate's "didFinishLaunching  " method .

1. Create and alloc instance of UINavigationController .
2. Add the UIViewController you want to be the landing page of the app as rootviewcontroller of navigation  controller.
3. Set the UINavigationController as the rootViewController of the application's window.

Once this is done, then you can push (show) and pop (remove) any UIViewController you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: user968597 Thanks for your reply but i want to handle it in the view controller which was added as childview controller in container view controller.